# In each group, only keep the row that contains the best choice

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column of Groups. I have another column with different choices. I want to only keep one row per group and to only keep the row containing the **best** choice. The choices in order of preference are First Choice, Second Choice, Third Choice, Fourth Choice.

My dataframe is much larger, so I need a scalable option, but here is an examples dataframe.

```
Group   Choice
Group1  First Choice
Group1  Second Choice
Group1  Third Choice
Group2  Third Choice
Group2  Fourth Choice
Group3  Second Choice
Group3  Fourth Choice
```

My desired output would be

```
Group   Choice
Group1  First Choice
Group2  Third Choice
Group3  Second Choice
```

recreatable dataframe code:

```
d = {'Group': ['Group1', 'Group1', 'Group1', 'Group2', 'Group2', 'Group3', 'Group3'], 'Choice': ['First Choice', 'Second Choice', 'Third Choice', 'Third Choice', 'Fourth Choice', 'Second Choice', 'Fourth Choice']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve this by creating a maping dict according to the order:

```
map_dict = {
    "First Choice" : 1,
    "Second Choice" : 2,
    "Third Choice" : 3,
    "Fourth Choice" : 4,
          }
```

so idea is to use that map_dict to get order number then sort the values using that order number and then drop duplicated value based on 'Group' column and drop that 'helper' column:

```
df=(df.assign(helper=df["Choice"].map(my_dict))
      .sort_values("helper").drop_duplicates(subset=["Group"]).drop(columns=["helper"]))
```

**OR**

Then other way around is by using `pd.CategoricalDtype`

Firstly create a list/tuple of values according to the order:

```
categories = ['First Choice', 'Second Choice', 'Third Choice', 'Fourth Choice']
```

the idea here is to use `pd.CategoricalDtype` to create that column as Categorical then sort values on basis of 'Choice' column and finally drop duplicates value on basis of group:

```
df["Choice"]=df["Choice"].astype((pd.CategoricalDtype(categories ,ordered=True)))
df=df.sort_values(by=["Choice"]).drop_duplicates(subset=["Group"])
```

**Note:** instead of using `drop_duplicates()` you can also use `groupby()`+`first()` methods as well

**output:**

```
    Group   Choice
0   Group1  First Choice
1   Group2  Third Choice
2   Group3  Second Choice
```

Answer (score 1):

We can proceed as follows :

```
my_dict = {
    "First Choice" : 1,
    "Second Choice" : 2,
    "Third Choice" : 3,
    "Fourth Choice" : 4,
          }
```

```
df['choice_#'] = df['Choice'].apply(lambda x: my_dict[x])
```

```
min_idx = df.groupby('Group')['choice_#'].idxmin()
min_df = df.loc[min_idx, ['Group', 'Choice', 'choice_#']].reset_index(drop=True)
min_df = min_df[['Group', 'Choice']]
```

**Output**

```
    Group   Choice
0   Group1  First Choice
1   Group2  Third Choice
2   Group3  Second Choice
```

Comment: Better should be `df.loc[df['Choice'].map(my_dict).groupby(df['Group']).idxmin()]`